# Ionic - Dynamic content inside ionic modal prevents to scroll upward

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll, modal-dialog

When I try to dynamically add content in MODAL(overflow-scroll is set false), the page adds white space at the bottom of page and prevents me to scroll up to reach the top of "ion-content".

Can anyone help me?

**My code:**

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    ....
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
       <ion-item ng-repeat="fc in query.filterChoices">
         ...
       </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-20">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-60">
            <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="addFilterChoice();">
                Add Filter
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-40">
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```